# Почему так выполняется этот код на Actionscript 3 и по другому на Javascript?

Tags: flash, actionscript

Собственно код:

```
var p:Object = { };
p.a = 1;
p.b = 1;
p.c = 1;
for (var prop:String in p) {
   trace(prop, p[prop]);
   p["a"] = 2;
}
```

и результат выполнения в Actionscript 3:

```
b 1
a 2
b 1
c 1
```

Comment: У меня:
  ******************
  a 1

  b 1

  c 1
  ******************

Comment: у меня в консоле браузера на js тоже так, а вот во флеше с трех компов пробовали

Comment: win7/x64, firefox, fp 11.1.102.55

Comment: Подозреваю что это связано с тем что actionscript компилируется в байт код еще на машине разраба, в связи с этим столь идиотский код он может оптимизировать так как посчитает нужным (ибо смысла в нем нет никакого), да и то что `a=2` - это 100% он, мне непонятно лишь откуда взялось `b`

Comment: давайте копать снизу:
- не верю чтоб все так плохо было, видимо замалчивается что то важное

- выкладывайте скомпиленый проект и исходники

- почему сравнивается ас3 код с ява скрипт? в чем смысл? там не то что виртуальные машины, синтаксис даже разный

- в чем собирается флешка?

- короче, простейший проект в студию

Comment: Пример взят отсюда:
http://www.parcsis.com/2010/02/05/mythbusters-truth-and-invention-about-flash/  решил проверить приведенный код

Comment: Фигней занимаетесь...

Какая разница что происходит между? Главное что результат одинаков везде, причина как я уже написал выше, с вероятность 99% в оптимизации в процессе компилирования. JS не оптимизируется, AS - оптимизируется, думаю причины пояснять не стоит.

Comment: Поясню сказанное @AlexWindHope:

Как вариант: Оптимизатор выносит из цикла `p["a"] = 2;`, т.к. данная строка "цикло-независимая", и получаем: 

    p["a"] = 2;
    for (var prop:String in p) trace(prop, p[prop]);

Comment: ок, почему тогда появляется вторая b?